# Why does AngularJS $scope.watch() stop working when I tell it to watch an Array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-scope, watch

I have an AngularJS application in which I create a directive `myp-my-directive` that draws a chart on the screen based on the attribute `my-attribute`. This is how I do it. It works:

HTML

```
<myp-my-directive my-attribute="[1, 2, 3]">
</myp-my-directive>
```

Angular Directive:

```
myapp.directive('mypMyDirective',function() {
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        myAttribute: '='
      },
      controller: 'StuffCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'stuffCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'myHtml.html'
    };
  }
);
```

Angular Controller:

```
myapp.controller('StuffCtrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.$watch(function() {return self.myAttribute;}, function (objVal)
      {
        if (!(typeof objVal === "object" && objVal.length > 0)) {

          var myObject = Object.assign({}, objVal.data);
          // Draw a fancy chart based using d3.js based on myObject
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
```

The above works.

But I just realized I will need to draw the chart based on 2 attributes, not just 1. I understand I can do this by returning an array to `$scope.$watch` instead of a single value, and passing a final argument `true` to it. For now (as an interim step) I adapted my controller to take an array containing one value to see if that would work. My controller now looks like this:

```
myapp.controller('StuffCtrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.$watch(function() {return [self.myAttribute];}, function (objVal)
      {
        if (!(typeof objVal[0] === "object" && objVal[0].length > 0)) {

          var myObject = Object.assign({}, objVal[0].data);
          // Draw a fancy chart based using d3.js based on myObject
        }
      }
    );
  }, true
);
```

But this produces the following error:

```
angular.js:13236 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at equals (angular.js:1048)
    at equals (angular.js:1058)
    at equals (angular.js:1074)
    at equals (angular.js:1058)
    at equals (angular.js:1074)
    at equals (angular.js:1058)
    at equals (angular.js:1074)
    at equals (angular.js:1058)
    at equals (angular.js:1074)
    at equals (angular.js:1058)
```

Why? Shouldn't the two versions of my controller be equivalent? Why is one working but the other failing? What is the best way to send in a second attribute to the controller from the directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for an array you have to use `$scope.$watchCollection()`. read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

try this

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {return [self.myAttribute];}, function (newVal, oldVal)
  {
    if (!(typeof newVal[0] === "object" && newVal[0].length > 0)) {

      var myObject = Object.assign({}, newVal[0].data);
      // Draw a fancy chart based using d3.js based on myObject
    }
  }
);
```